# R dataframe replace value from another dataframe conditional

Tags: r, dataframe, conditional-statements

I have two dataframes. One with nunbers, and one with status (TRUE or FALSE).

```
df1<-data.frame(A=c(14,25,37),B=c(12,45,23),C=c(65,29,67))
df2<-data.frame(A=c('FALSE','TRUE','TRUE'),B=c('TRUE','FALSE','FALSE'),C=c('TRUE','TRUE','FALSE'))
```

I would like to copy value from df1 to df2, if df2 is TRUE.

```
df3<-data.frame(A=c('FALSE',25,37),B=c(12,'FALSE','FALSE'),C=c(65,29,'FALSE'))
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one option:

```
df3 <- df2
df3[df3 == 'TRUE'] <- df1[df3 == 'TRUE']

df3
      A     B     C
1 FALSE    12    65
2    25 FALSE    29
3    37 FALSE FALSE
```

### Demo

Note: For the above code to work verbatim, I had to slightly alter your definition of `df2` to use `stringsAsFactors=FALSE`.  With character data only, it is easy to check for `'TRUE'`.